# Push to array and create running total

Tags: javascript, arrays, cumulative-sum

I need to push the height of each page into an array. However the/my problem is, that I need to push not the values themselves, but a running total of the values.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var heights = [0];
$('.page').each(function(i) {
    heights.push($(this).height());
});
```

The result looks like this: `[0, 2000, 1000, 3000, 1500]`, which is the heights of the pages,
but I need something like this: `[0, 2000, 3000, 6000, 7500]`, which is the running total of the page heights added.

Comment: do you mean `[2000, 3000, 6000, 7500]`?

Comment: so you want it sorted? just use .sort(); after inserting.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Whoops, yes! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var heights = [0];
$('.page').each(function(i) {
    heights.push(
        $(this).height() + (heights[i] || 0)
    );
});
```

**EDIT**
Edited version now incorporates the leading `0` array member as requested by the questioner.

Answer (score 2):

Add this after the code you have:

```
var total = 0;
for (i=1 ; i < heights.length ; ++i) {
    total += heights[i];
    heights[i] = total;
}
```

Comment: @yckart There. Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single loop:

```
var heights = [];
var total   = 0;
$('.page').each(function(i) {
    total += $(this).height();
    heights.push(total);
});
```

Or... if you want it to be super clean:

```
var heights = [];
var total   = 0;
$('.page').each((function(){
  var total = 0;
  return function(i) {
    total += $(this).height();
    heights.push(total);
  };
}()));
```

The second version avoids polluting any scopes with the `total` variable.

Comment: The leading 0 doesn't really change much of the answer.